# installing specific apt package

Tags: apt

im using ubuntu 16 and need mysql-server lower than 5.7.28
i try this steps:

```
root@hr:~# apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
     5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.11-0ubuntu6 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

so i want to install the 5.7.11-0ubuntu6 package

```
root@hr:~# apt install mysql-server=5.7.11-0ubuntu6 -V
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
   mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-common (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
Suggested packages:
   mailx
   tinyca (0.7.5-6)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-common (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-server (5.7.11-0ubuntu6)
   mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
   mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

if i click yes it will install al this packages 
after apt finishing installing the packages i check mysql -V but and getting

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

what am i doing wrong ? 
how can i install the desired version ?

as  @BanAnanas suggested
i added the /etc/apt/preferences file with this lines:

```
Package: mysql-server-5.7
Pin: version 5.7.11-0ubuntu6
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
root@hr:~# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Fetched 325 kB in 8s (38.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done


root@hr:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.11-0ubuntu6) but 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


root@hr:~# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libtimedate-perl liburi-perl
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.


root@hr:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.11-0ubuntu6) but 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


root@hr:~# apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server-5.7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.7.11-0ubuntu6
  Version table:
     5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.11-0ubuntu6 1001
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

can i use synaptic on ubuntu server  ?

Comment: I think it might have to be done manually by setting priorities. Priorities are numbers in front of each version https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121413/understanding-the-output-of-apt-cache-policy.  
Take a look at 6.2.5. Managing Package Priorities to see how to set priorities and force lower version to install https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.apt-get.en.html

Comment: More under The Effect of APT Preferences: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/apt_preferences.5.html
(I might write an entire answer later)

Comment: You can force a downgrade to an older version using `synaptic`...but it can turn into a minefield of dependency issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The APT preferences file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) `/etc/apt/preferences` and the fragment files in the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` folder can be used to control which versions of packages will be selected for installation. By default, atp will never downgrade unless the priority of an available version exceeds `1000`.
To solve this you have to set priority of version `5.7.11-0ubuntu6` to `1001`.

Open/create file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences
```

Add this entry to the file and save it:

```
Package: mysql-server-5.7
Pin: version 5.7.11-0ubuntu6
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Priority higher than `1000` causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a downgrade of the package.

To apply the change run:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
```

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.11-0ubuntu6) but 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Comment: As @Organic Marble predicted, there are some dependencies issues. I suggest you try this solutions, and  try to install again after each:
1) `sudo apt-get update` 
2) (installing) and opening `synaptic`, `Edit -> Fix broken Packages`
3) `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: What's the new output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.7`? Has priority changed to `1001` and which version is Candidate?